# In search of a solution to preload icons in Windows icon cache only for a specific folder

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, icons, thumbnails, thumbs.db

As you probably know, **Windows XP** has a feature of thumbnail caching. On each directory with photos you can find a hidden **thumbs.db** file that stores folder and file thumbnail references, that "thumbs.db" file stores the cache for Windows Explorer's thumbnail view to reduce thumbnail loading times, so that folder content doesn't need to be recalculated every time the folder is viewed and this mean it will load much faster.

This feature was reworked on newer Windows versions. Now on **Windows 10** we have just a single and "temporal" **thumbcache_xxx.db** (numbered by size) in a single folder, which acts to store folder and file thumbnails from any directory that you view on your machine.

A rework does not mean an improvement, this concept fails for directories with a large amount of files and/or images, or with loads of folders with custom icons (specified in the hidden desktop.ini file), because its just now a single **thumbcache_xxx.db** file that stores all thumbnails from all the directories, and it has a size limit... that you can increase by hacking the Windows registry, but at the end you will have a very big thumbnails cache file full of junk references inside and you will end up deleting/renew the thumbnail cache for the sake of god.

In my opinion, It would be much, much simpler if **Microsoft** let people the personal decision to be able generate single **thumbs.db** files for specific folders while the newer **thumbcache_xxx.db** concept still does it's job with other directories that does not have a **thumbs.db** file, I mean both concepts could live together.

---

Now, my problem and question:

I have a directory with around ~2000 folders with custom icons (I mean, each folder has a hidden desktop.ini file that indicates a custom icon file for thumbnail preview), an example of what I mean:

[image]

so every time that I view that directory, I must face the very high load times to complete icons extraction (note are icons, not thumbnails) and caching for all folders (more than 5 minutes) while I try to scroll down with the scrollbar to let windows slowly generate the rest of icon cache. It's a pain, too slow and clunky.

Increasing the max. allocation size for **IconCache_xxx.db** is not a valid solution for me, because I don't want a single file that messes all the icons references from that directory with 2000 folders together with references from all other directories on my disk. I just would like to have a single **thumbs.db** for that directory with 2000 folders, inside that directory, so that file will preserve the cache of the icons I want to preserve and nothing more, so that folder content wouldn't need to be recalculated anymore every time the folder is viewed and this mean it will load much faster. But It seems can't do this in a proper way with **Windows 10** thumbnail cache features...

Exists a solution for this?. What are my options at this point?. Which could be an acceptable approach to solve this problem I face? (not returning to use **Windows XP** of course).

I searched the Internet to try find any program or shell extension or just some thing that could hack/bypass **IconCache_xxx.db** features in order to let me generate **thumbs.db** files for specific directories, but it seems does not exists anything similar like that.

Is there any magical registry value that I can set to be able generate **thumbs.db** files for each directory like in **Windows XP** era?. Any alternative then?.

---

> UPDATE:

I found the open-source program [WinThumbsPreloader](https://github.com/bruhov/WinThumbsPreloader), it is awesome for people that has the same problem I have, but for thumbnails.

The problem I have is with the icon cache, not the thumbnail cache. So, **WinThumbsPreloader** can't help me because it does not cache folder or file icons, it only caches folder/file thumbnails.

I need to be able to do the same thing **WinThumbsPreloader** does, but for folder icons instead of file thumbnails. select a directory arbitrarily and preload its folder icons in the Windows icon cache.

Comment: Please give an example of one `desktop.ini` of yours. Are the referred images thumbnail-size or much larger? Are they `.ico` files?

Comment: @harrymc thanks for comment. All the images referenced in my desktop.ini files (with no exception) are multi-layered .ico files with these sizes inside: 256x256, 128x128, 96x96, 48x48, 32x32, 24x24 and 16x16. Here is a folder sample: https://mediafire.com/file/pcomizv46ewrtf6/sample.zip/file - also if it can be of interest I opened a related programming question about this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61987130/preload-thumbnail-for-a-specific-folder-in-windows-thumbnail-cache-in-c-sharp-o

Comment: Is it possible for you to browse the thumbnails using something else, e.g. [IrfanView Thumbnails tool](https://www.google.com/search?q=irfanview+thumbnails&tbm=isch) which bypasses the Windows cache completely and always reads images without caching?

Comment: @miroxlav not really, I depend on Explorer.exe. thanks for comment

Comment: Your icons are enormous at 258 KB each, which might be why you are exploding the cache. For 2000 of them you would need a cache of half a GB, which I saw somewhere is more than Windows allows. Perhaps reducing the size of your icons to at least half, keeping only one or two sizes, will help here.

Answer (score 1):

The thumb-cache files seem to have an upper limit on their total size.
On the other hand, your icons are very large at 258 KB each.
With ~2000 icons, your cache could be of about half a gigabyte.

When the maximal size is reached, Windows will delete icons,
starting with the oldest.
This might explain why you are losing icons from the cache and needing to
regenerate them again.

Reducing the sizes of the icons might be one solution to the problem.

This same problem was also  discussed by users in the post
[After fall update, Windows 10 puts a maximum size on thumbnail cache and deletes older thumbnails before new ones can be generated](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/after-fall-update-windows-10-puts-a-maximum-size/6ad0a1e7-38c0-4547-9b8b-f7f3906c3a12?page=1).

According to the experiments by the poster of the above link,
the `thumbcache_96.db` file tops off at 349 MB.

Another user found inadvertently a workaround for the problem:

> holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on the keyboard and rolling the mouse wheel
>   one tick up.
>
> This apparently has forced Windows Explorer to render the thumbnails
>   at a higher resolution, which means that they are no longer suitable
>   to be stored in the  _96.db file, but instead, in the _256.db file.
>
> I set this view as default for all pictures folders by clicking the
>   File menu in the Explorer window and selecting "Change folder and
>   search options" to open the "Folder Options" window, then selecting
>   tab View and clicking on Apply to folders under Folder Views.
>
> I believe the file thumbcache_256.db must have a hard limit to its
>   size like its counterpart, but it seems to be considerably higher, as
>   my file is currently sitting at 1,334,272KB and still growing.

Displaying larger icons might solve the problem for you, but flush your icons
first using Disk Cleanup. If this option is not available for cleanup,
see the last entry in the above linked post.

Comment: Hi.First of all thanks for answer but I must clarify some important things: 1. I never said that the problem is: "losing icons from the cache and needing to regenerate them again". The problem is that I just would like to preload a set of folder icons in the windows icon (not thumbnail) cache,regardless of whether if I have those icons already cached or I have zero cached icons.I just need to do the same thing "WinThumbsPreloader" program does,but for icons instead of thumbnails.For this reason,and with all my respects to you,the file size of my icons has nothing to do with the problem I have.

Comment: 2.I have a size limit of 4096 MB (4 GB) for the cache files,this size can be set via registry value (note the limit can be set to a bigger size,like 8 GB,but that will cause performance issues).I ensured my cache files (at least "IconCache_256.db",which is the one that Windows uses more to store folder icons) can occupy more than 1 GB file size,then it does not have that "hard limit" of the conjectures of those experiments,and does not delete old cached images unless I manually rebuild/delete the cache (I also set the 'automatic maintenance' via registry to avoid deleting old cached images).

Comment: 3. Probably the next thing to clarify was a mistake from my side when I was redacting the question, I'm sorry to cause confusion, but I always tried to refer to the icon cache, not the thumbnail cache. At the start (when I redacted the question) I had my doubts because I was not sure whether Windows was extracting/caching icons or thumbnails for folders, but now is clear, the custom folder icons are stored in "IconCache_*.db" files and NOT in "ThumbCache_*.db" files, then my problem and question is about the icon cache system only. I upvoted your answer, thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Correction noted. If I understand right, you increased in the registry the `Max Cached Icons` to 4096, which should have fixed the problem. How big is IconCache_256.db after the icons are fully displayed?

Comment: As I mentioned in the main topic, increasing the limit via that registry value is not a solution for my real problem, but yes, it solves the initial limit. Answering to your question: with a empty icon cache, and for a sample of 1.800 folders with custom icons, my **IconCache_256.db** increases to ~180 MB. **IconCache_16.db** to ~4 MB and **IconCache_32.db** to ~10 MB, while **_96.db**, **_768.db**, **_1280.db**, **_1920.db**, **_2560.db**, **_custom_stream.db**, **_exif.db**, **_sr.db**, **_wide.db** and **_wide_alternate.db** are not modified (file size remains 24 bytes for all of them)

Comment: What actions are you **mostly** doing when viewing the 1800 folders? Playing?

Comment: Just in a "clear" scenario (no unnecessary programs opened, no playing games or music/video files) on which I open Explorer.exe to navigate to that directory with 1800 folders, and using the vertical scrollbar down to continue and finish extracting and caching all the folder icons of that directory, then I go to the folder where "IconCache_*db" files are to see their file size. Why are you asking this?. What do you have in mind about?.

Comment: I'm thinking in three directions: (1) Disabling icons for all folders except this one, (2) Setting a sandbox environment for only this folder, (3) Backup and restore of IconCache_256.db for only this folder. If one is suitable for you.